# GroupBy and Count using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, count

I have a **class** called Component with following properties:

```
public class Component
{
    public string VerticalType {get; set;}
    public string ProductCode {get; set;}
}
```

And I have a **list**:

```
public List<Component> ComponentList;
```

and say have following **items** in it the list:

```
Internet   54896
TV         24859
Video      48596
Internet   35969
```

I have a Dictionary and I want to fill it with VerticalType as key and Count as Value. So my dictionary would look like this:

```
(Internet,2)
(TV,1)
(Video,1)
```

I am trying something like this but have no clue how to get the count.

```
var results = lead.SelectedOffer.ComponentList.GroupBy(
     p => p.VerticalType,
     p => p.VerticalTypeCount,
     (key, g) => new { VerticalType = key, Count =  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count in a group, you use the `Count()` method:

```
Count = g.Count()
```

On another note, since all you want is a mapping from `VerticalType` to the count then I'd suggest going for:

```
lead.SelectedOffer.ComponentList.GroupBy(p => p.VerticalType)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

or if you want to persist with the IEnumerable of the anonymous types then you still don't need this specific overload of `GroupBy` you're using in your example code but rather this overload:

```
lead.SelectedOffer.ComponentList.GroupBy(p => p.VerticalType)
                  .Select(g => new { VerticalType = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll go with the first suggestion

Comment: One more thing. I am getting convertion error when I assign it to dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: @HumaAli yes, that's because the resulting type is `Dictionary<string, int>` where `string` is the `VerticalType` and the `int` is the corresponding count.

Comment: Ahh Got it. Thanks